# Установить / сменить второй фон (background-image) на CSS

Tags: css

Есть несколько блоков с разными фонами. Возможно ли добавлять им второй фон на CSS, например, по наведению?

```
.class:hover {
background-image: url(здесь как-то сохраняется оригинальный фон блока), 
url(добавляется второй фон);
}
```

Блоков многовато, поэтому вариант для каждого просто копировать оригинальный фон + приписывать второй не слишком подходит. Нужно решение для всех блоков разом.

Comment: Нельзя установить 2 фона сразу.

Comment: Скорее всего вряд ли получится сохранить оригинальный фон: hover его переопределит. Тут либо явно указывать в стилях, либо исхитряться с наложением блоков друг на друга, а hover для верхнего прописывать.

Comment: покажите html  ..

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: Автор либо хочет глупость, либо не может объяснить что конкретно у него не получается.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите, [но гляньте тут](https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/multiple), может это вас натолкнет на идею.

Answer (score 2):

Идеи иссякли...

```js
function fAddBgImage(sClass, sImageAndPos) {
  let aBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(sClass);
  let aImageAndPos = sImageAndPos.split(' ');
  aBlocks.forEach(function(element) {
    sBgImage = getComputedStyle(element).backgroundImage;
    sBgPos = getComputedStyle(element).backgroundPosition;
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
      element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + aImageAndPos[0] + '), ' + sBgImage;
      element.style.backgroundPosition = aImageAndPos[1] + ' ' + aImageAndPos[2] + ', ' + sBgPos;
    })
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
      element.style.backgroundImage = '';
      element.style.backgroundPosition = '';
    })
  });
}
fAddBgImage('.class_script', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3a0245702f6ce1969137e44750ca54a9?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG -20% -20%');
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.class_manual,
.class_before,
.class_after,
.class_script {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  font: 14px 'Arial';
  color: #ffdb00;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

.class_manual {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJi51.jpg?s=328&g=1);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.class_manual:hover {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3a0245702f6ce1969137e44750ca54a9?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJi51.jpg?s=328&g=1);
  background-position: -20% -20%, 0px 0px;
}

.class_before {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJi51.jpg?s=328&g=1);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.class_before:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3a0245702f6ce1969137e44750ca54a9?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-position: -20% -20%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.class_after {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJi51.jpg?s=328&g=1);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.class_after:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3a0245702f6ce1969137e44750ca54a9?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-position: -20% -20%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.class_script {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJi51.jpg?s=328&g=1);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="class_manual"><strong>С использованием ручной правки</strong><br><em>Не подходит, в виду большого количества блоков с разными фонами. Здесь для образца.</em></div>
  <div class="class_before"><strong>С использованием псевдоэлемента ::before</strong><br><em>Подходит не для всякой цели, т.к. перекрывает содержимое родительского блока.</em></div>
  <div class="class_after"><strong>С использованием псевдоэлемента ::after</strong><br><em>Подходит не для всякой цели, т.к. вытесняется содержимым родительского блока.</em></div>
  <div class="class_script"><strong>С использованием JavaScript</strong><br><em>Простой, надёжный и удобный способ, управлять фоновым изображением из скрипта.</em></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@UModeL , чтобы псевдоэлемент не перекрывал содержимое блока, нужно его(содержимое) обернуть в элемент и задать `position:relative`.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.block{
  max-width:300px;
  margin:20px auto 0;
  padding:20px;
  background:linear-gradient(#cda,#acd);
  position:relative;
}
.block__content{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.block:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:0;
  opacity:0;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at center,#cda,#dac) no-repeat center/80%;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}
.block:hover:before{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam fugit obcaecati laborum natus ad odio inventore facere similique reprehenderit quod!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: таким образом нужно будет добавлять дополнительный `div` для каждого блока. У меня обёртка стоит только для выравнивания примеров, а сами блоки, как в исходных условиях - оформление через CSS.

Comment: @UModeL , можно и не добавлять лишний элемент, а задать `position:relative` непосредственным потомкам блока: `.block>*{position:relative}` . Просто  с обёрткой, на мой взгляд, правильнее.

Comment: првильнее, это да... Просто мы не знаем, какой контент будет в блоках. Если это будет простой текст (без `p`, `em`, `b`, `span` и т.п.), то нечему будет относительно позиционироваться))

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте им общий класс. Например:

```
.item_1 {

  background-image: url("../img/bg1.jpg");
}

.item_2 {

  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg");
}

.item:hover {

  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
}

    <div class="list">
        <div class="item item_1"></div>
        <div class="item item_2"></div>
        <div class="item item_3"></div>
        <div class="item item_4"></div>
    </div>
```